# Any way to know the latest eclipse history files for particular classes?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using,

-Java Development Kit 8

and,

-Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

-Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
-Build id: 20150219-0600

I had the unfortunate experience of deleting a project that I thought I had saved in another folder. However that save turned out to be just a file path save. Now I have used a few different techniques to try and find the old project (local history, data recovery, ect...). Finally I had success by going to my workspace then going here,

```
  .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.history
```

However there are over 700 files in the time period that I edited it. The program had at least 30 different classes. ? I can easily drag and drop all the folders into an editor, but then how do I know the latest version of the class?

I have tried sorting by date modified as I mentioned earlier.

[click here to see an image of me sorting it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGV0p.jpg) The issue is that there is about 30 different classes in all of these files. what is the fastest way to know which ones belong to which classes?